# What is the purpose and duration of the Plinth Prize scholarship?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hunger-games, the-ballad-of-songbirds-and-snakes

In *The Hunger Games: The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes* (2023) the Plinth Prize scholarship is mentioned.

Can someone explain how many years this scholarship was given out and its primary purpose or significance in the context of the movie's story?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a

> "gigantic monetary sum"

as well as

> "access to the highest reaches of government"

and possibly even

> "a prestigious apprenticeship in the War Department"

according to Lucky Flickerman.

The actual sum isn't confirmed in either the book or the film, but it appears to be sufficient to pay Coriolanus' university fees with enough left over to pay off his family's debts.

---

The purpose in the film is to act as Coryo's primary motivation for his candidate to do well in the Hunger Games. If he succeeds, his future will be bright and secure. If he fails, he won't be able to go to university, his family will lose their house and he'll need to get a humdrum job.

> Whatever it was, Coriolanus needed to set it right. He could not risk losing his prize over such a thing. After university he planned to embark on some lucrative profession. Without an education, what doors would be open to him? He tried to imagine his future in some low-level city position . . . doing what?
>
> <sub><sup>[The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/51901147)</sup></sub>

In the [source novel](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/51901147) there were various 'Academy prizes' on offer, but the driver was much the same, to allow him to go to university.

> And if she did, would that weaken his chance for one of the Academy prizes presented at graduation? Without such a prize, he had no way to afford to go to university, which meant no career, which meant no future, not for him, and who knew what would happen to the family...

In the book this is the first year that the 'Plinth Prize' was on offer.

> “Yes,” Sejanus finally began. “We, the Plinth family, would like to announce that we will be giving a prize for a full ride to the University to the mentor whose tribute wins the Hunger Games.”

Whereas in the film it's mentioned as having been run for several years.

> **Gaul:** *Eager to learn who’s won that Plinth Prize, no doubt. And a golden future. However, I am here to tell you that there has been **a change this year.***

Comment: +1 …as with any [MacGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin) it doesn't really matter what it is, just so long as it motivates one or more characters to chase their plot line.